# Collapsing Bottom Bar (like Google Music) in Android

Tags: android

I know how to implement a collapsing toolbar with the android design library.
But how do i implement a collapsing bottom bar like the one that is implemented in [googles play music app](http://i.giphy.com/l41lGf55cvMO0HeEM.gif)?

Comment: hey, did you find your answer ? Can you please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274623/how-to-show-mini-controller-at-bottom-or-persistent-media-controls-like-spotify